# 'Required property 'type' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.template.parameters.factoryName', line 1, position 208.'

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I'm attempting to publish our development ADF objects from our development subscription to our test subscription.

To accomplish this, I used the Microsoft guide to set up a [release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-automate-azure-pipelines). My final result looks like this:

[image: Configured values]

However, when attempting to deploy to test, it fails:

```
2022-05-04T12:22:05.6519328Z ##[section]Starting: ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope 2022-05-04T12:22:05.6923741Z
============================================================================== 2022-05-04T12:22:05.6925480Z Task         : ARM template deployment 2022-05-04T12:22:05.6925967Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template to all the deployment scopes 2022-05-04T12:22:05.6926257Z Version      : 3.200.0 2022-05-04T12:22:05.6926589Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation 2022-05-04T12:22:05.6927048Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment 2022-05-04T12:22:05.6927663Z
============================================================================== 2022-05-04T12:22:06.5933183Z ARM Service Connection deployment scope - Subscription 2022-05-04T12:22:06.6193437Z Checking if the following resource group exists: tst-<Removed>. 2022-05-04T12:22:06.8901626Z Resource group exists: true. 2022-05-04T12:22:06.8904567Z Creating deployment parameters. 2022-05-04T12:22:06.9013317Z The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\Dev\dev-adf-<Removed>\ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json' is 'utf-8' 2022-05-04T12:22:06.9064165Z (node:4736) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.0403949Z Starting template validation. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.0478298Z Deployment name is ARMTemplateParametersForFactory-20220504-122207-af92 2022-05-04T12:22:07.3412253Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidRequestContent. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.3458400Z
##[error]The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Required property 'type' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.template.parameters.factoryName', line 1, position 208.'. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.3475499Z ##[warning]Validation errors were found in the Azure Resource Manager template. This can potentially cause template deployment to fail. Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.. Please follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax 2022-05-04T12:22:07.3477016Z Starting Deployment. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.3477522Z Deployment name is ARMTemplateParametersForFactory-20220504-122207-af92 2022-05-04T12:22:07.4293852Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: InvalidRequestContent. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.4295964Z
##[error]The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Required property 'type' not found in JSON. Path 'properties.template.parameters.factoryName', line 1, position 208.'. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.4298521Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting 2022-05-04T12:22:07.4301572Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment. 2022-05-04T12:22:07.4465058Z
##[section]Finishing: ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope
```

The contents of the ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "factoryName": {
            "value": "dev-adf-<removed>"
        },
        "<removed>_EDW_connectionString": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "dev_blob_<removed>_connectionString": {
            "value": ""
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is no line 208 in that file. The logs are not helpful at all, and to the best of my knowledge, I have not made any changes to the parameter file.

I have tried reading related questions, but they all seem to deal with different issues or are not related to Data Factory projects. Checking other files within the adf_publish branch, I did see some of them had a `"type":"string"` property. I attempted to manually add that to the ArmTemplateParametersForDataFactory file as well, but the error remains.

I'm franmkly not sure how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just in case you've not seen that yet, check if any of the errors documented in the troubleshooting guide helps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ci-cd-github-troubleshoot-guide
Also the fact that it shows line 1, position 208 is probably just because it flattens the content and attempts to point to somewhere in that file. Try to check your dev env again to see if it's properly published/updated etc